# Вызов в Applet'e браузера с определенной страницей

Tags: applet, java

Написал простую программу, апплет, который выводит просто изображение, при щелчке мыши на которое открывается браузер, вопрос в том, как сделать, чтобы в этом браузере открывалась определенная страница?

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял задачу, то как то так:

```
getAppletContext().showDocument(new URL("http://some.url"), "_blank");
```